# How can I use cycles to bake vertex colors of multiple meshes at once?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, vertex-colors

I'm trying to bake lighting into vertex colors of meshes in a scene, using the following method:

- change to Cycles rendering (*Render > Render Engine > Cycles*)
- Add a color attribute to each 3D object.
- Set bake target to *Active Color Attribute* (under *Render > Bake*)
- Click *Bake*

This works fine when baking for a single object, but I want to be able to bake for multiple objects at the same time.
However, when I click *Bake* after having selected multiple objects, I get an error saying `Mesh does not have an active color attribute "Cube.194"`.

I've tried selecting the color attribute in the *Data* tab, but it seems like I can only select it for a single object at a time, so baking won't work with multiple objects selected.

Is there any way I can bake light into vertex colors of multiple meshes at the same time?